# Analyzing individual + aggregate-level data (with individual DV) : what statistical model to use?

Tags: multiple-regression, multilevel-analysis, nonlinear-regression

Greetings,

I have pooled cross-sectional survey data spanning several decades. Separately, using LexisNexis, I also created an index of issue-salience that stores the % of monthly newspaper articles that mention or refer to specific words/terms. I then merged the latter (aggregate-level) data to the former (pooled individual-level survey data). My outcome variable is dichotomous. My individual-level predictor variables include ideology, party affiliation, sex, education, religious service attendance, age, and year. As suggested, I'd like to also test the effects of the newspaper index. My question is what type of model would be appropriate to use in doing so? Would a standard logit/probit model suffice (is it suitable for regressing on individual and aggregate-level variables?)? Thanks in advance for your help!